# Show sample rate pass on Yafaray

Tags: rendering, external-applications, render-passes

Is there a way to render an anti-aliasing sample rate pass on Yafaray like V-Ray does?

[image]

This is extremely useful to fine-tune the render settings and have a quality output without cranking the AA settings high up.

I've seen something like this on the Yafaray documentation (on the render settings chapter about AA threshold) but I couldn't find a way to render it:

[image]

Comment: AFAIK yafaray doesn't support render passes :/

Comment: I'm currently trying to implement Render Passes functionality in YafaRay and this looks interesting. Please will you explain more in detail what this pass should do? If possible I would try to implement it.

Comment: @DavidBluecame if you are interested in implementing this, please refer to this link: http://www.cggallery.com/tutorials/vray_optimization/  its very useful to understand about this concept

Answer (score 4):

I've released YafaRay-E (experimental) v2.0.0, which includes Render Passes, Render Views and, among other things, there is a samplerate pass available that shows the places where the adaptative AA is sampling more pixels. It's not exactly what you showed here, but I hope it's good enough.

You can download it from here:

http://www.yafaray.org/community/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=5132

Best regards.